# SHA256, SHA1, SHA384 hash to JSON Web Token

Tags: jwt

Is it possible to generate a JSON Web Token from a SHA384 Hash. If it is possible please advice how it is possible.
Also please generate JSON Web Token from my SHA384 hash:

```
e648d207eb6a457cc3b415e5e6db38759de529051d808b5d34c679c43020a233e6b5161de2e85070127009d61e4c24c8
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273). What do you mean by "generate JSON Web Token from my SHA384 hash"? That task/approach doesn't make any sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

No, converting a hash into a JWT token is not possible and I also can't see why/for what anyone would want this.

As mentioned in the comment, that approach does't make any sense at all.

A hash doesn't contain any readable information that you could convert into anything.

You could create a token that contains a hash in the payload, if this is what you mean.

JWTs are usually signed. The SHA algorithm, e.g. HS256 (HMAC-SHA256), can be used to sign a token.
That means that a hash is calculated from the header and payload plus your secret and the hash value is then base64url encoded and attached to the token as a signature.

You can read this [introduction](https://jwt.io/introduction/) to learn more about JWT.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible in Laravel version 7.
While converting jwt hash token to shal, go to EloquentUserProvider.php

```
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
    {
        $plain = $credentials['password'];
        
        if(sha1($plain) == $user->getAuthPassword()) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
// return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
```

Comment: Can you share more details? How would the given hash be converted?

Comment: *While converting jwt hash token to shal* - what does that mean? And the code just shows how a password is getting hashed to compare it to a password hash, how is this related to JWT or the question? It's unclear what you want to tell us.